# Persistent error : http status 503

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3, glassfish-embedded

Here's the scenario:

At work, for a glassfish server, i'm having a persistent error http status 503, whenever I test a specific wsdl (corresponding to a specific glassfish module),  in a web browser.

For te same server glassfish, i have other wsdl's corresponding to other glassfish modules. I've tested these very same wsdl's and it works.

I've already tried to :

- Desactivate and Activate the glassfish module ;
- Reinstall again the problematique glassfish module ;
- Reinstall an older version of the very same glassfish module 
  (Returns http status 503);
- Ping pools fron the server glassfish
- Reboot only the glassfish server ;
- Reboot the physical machine ;

Despite all these actions, i'm having weird error messages in the log file that i don't understand. Can anyone please help ?

Thanks in advance.

**Log file** :

> [#|2018-06-19T23:34:21.311+0200|SEVERE|sun-appserver2.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=Thread-200;_RequestID=c23284fb-2dea-4a9a-86fc-5d764902c84a;|WebModule[/echange_operateur]PWC1275: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class fr.bouyguestelecom.dolmen.access.ftth.exchange.servlet.TimerServletListener
>
> javax.ejb.EJBException: Unable to complete container-managed transaction.; nested exception is: javax.transaction.SystemException: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: JTS5022: Unexpected exception [com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.LogException: Log exception at point 14:
>
> LOG-003: Read failure] from log.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
>
> javax.transaction.SystemException: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: JTS5022: Unexpected exception [com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.LogException: Log exception at point 14:
>
> LOG-003: Read failure] from log.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
>            at fr.bouyguestelecom.dolmen.access.ftth.exchange.servlet.TimerServletListener.contextInitialized(TimerServletListener.java:22)
>
> javax.ejb.EJBException: Unable to complete container-managed transaction.; nested exception is: javax.transaction.SystemException: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: JTS5022: Unexpected exception [com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.LogException: Log exception at point 14:
>
> LOG-003: Read failure] from log.  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can not figure out the error messages found in the log file, but I've managed to solve the problem by :

- Stop problematic Glassfish module ;
- Restart glassfish Server ;
- Start problematic Glassfish module ;

After this action I got a response from the wsdl.
I hope it can help other people with the same or similar probleme.